# Modify files between different owners/users; Samba

Tags: ubuntu, files, permissions, users, samba

I need to share a directory to a group and that every user can modify files created by a different owner. For example a document file that needs to be constantly updated by different users.

I already created folder, allowed group to read and write that folder, but if user a creates a file it cannot be modified by user b, although it has read permissions.
Users: a, b
Group: editorial
Directory: editorial

If I type `ls -la editorial`, output is:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 a editorial 4096 apr 3 11:42 editorial
```

note: last "editorial" word in output is highlighted.

Can someone please help me to make files writable by any user since the moment they are created?

Thanks in advance, cheers.

PS: I'm on Ubuntu in case it's useful.

Comment: what does your smb.conf file say for the editorial directory? you probably need a `writeable = yes` for that mount point.

Comment: settings are:
[editorial]
path = /dir/editorial
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
valid users = @editorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of the directory is already editorial so you can use `setgid` so that any files and directories created inside of that directory have the group as editorial which allows anyone in that group to modify files and directories created by anyone else.

From the directory right above:

`chmod g+s editorial`

In all cases, I strongly advise against setting permissions as 777.

Comment: This was essential to solve my problem, thanks. I also added: "write list = @group" to smb.conf for editorial directory and kept directory permissions as 770. Thank you and @fcbsd.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.